# Should I avoid booting my MacBook if it's really cold?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

As the title says; if my MacBook has been exposed to minus degrees, should I wait for it to reach room temperature before I boot it or am I just paranoid and have nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends how “minus”. In general, li-on batteries live longer if you respect their acceptable operating temperatures. In the case of your Macbook Pro, [Apple](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html) has a dedicated page with tips about Battery Maintenance.

If you observe the temperature graph on the left, the Minus degrees are not in the “I like this” zone.

Truth is, your MBP will get warm relatively fast, but if your MBP is at 0ºC, I’d wait a little bit. At those temperatures, depending upon the dew point and the humidity (among other factors) the risk of running moisture is higher, especially if the MBP will start heating fast when you turn it on.

Just let the machine heat for a few minutes at room temperature to be safe. Of course, if you *have* to use it one day, the battery is not going to die on you. Remember, extreme temperatures are enemies of batteries!

The cold Swedish tundra is not a friendly place for a Li-on battery :)

Comment: good suggestion. are there guidelines for usage of MBP/ Apple products in cold winters ? Any link with info, is appreciated ! Chicago's weather becomes very cold in winters, so need to have some pro-tips. How about using outside of the your home ?

Comment: I don’t really have links with info, I’ll see if I can find something. Where I live we rarely get below −5ºC, but the OP seems to be living in Sweeden, things go beyond −10ºC there, both temperatures are way beyond the recommended operating range of the products. To put it in another way… Apple says: use this between 10ºC and 25ºC. (for example). But I’ve exceeded those values countless of times. Make sure you don’t let your macbook freeze as it would in “The day after”… ;)

Comment: @Zolomon ;) I know what it is, I was born in the exact opposite side of the world, tho not as close as the south pole as Sweden is to the north pole, there isn’t anything else… well… the Antarctica :)

Comment: By the way, it's called Sweden (one E is enough, even though it's a lovely character! ;)

Comment: @Zolomon corrected in the email, ty. (I put it right in the comments tho’). I’ve been in Sweden a couple of times, very nice!